# is there any way to navigate into two different App container react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

hi i"m new to react native i'm trying to build my first app
i'm having some trouble with react navigation I've done two different app container the first contain the startup Screen ,login,Signup, and Main which  is the second app container that contain my other screenStacks now I've tried to implement a logout functionality but i couldn't managed how i can go back to the first app container that contain the login Screen 
i'm using react navigation 3.0
i don't know if this is possible to manage ???
any help please ,thank you :)

```
-App
      |
       StarutUPScreen
       SignIn
      Signout
       Main
      ....

  -Main
        |
         mainScreen
         other Screens
          ....
```

```
export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      StartUpScreen,
      IntroOneScreen,
      IntroTwoScreen,
      IntroThreeScreen,
      SignIn,
      SignUp,
      ForgotPassword,
      Main (the other container)
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "StartUpScreen"
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

there should be only one app container

you can create multiple stack navigator and nest them together

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({...});
// this will have only screens from main stack

const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator({...,MainNavigator});
// root navigator will have auth part and then main stack

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

// Now AppContainer is the main component for React to render

export default AppContainer;
```

Comment: the main Navigator contains many  different  StackNavigator nested  to a botomTab navigator so it's still possible to manage  with your solution am i right?

Comment: yes, instead of `createStackNavigator` use `createBottomTabNavigator`

Comment: i'm already using that that's why i didn't knew how to manage  that you can check my code here [link](https://snack.expo.io/@ahmedsaadi/navigation)  thank you

Comment: in Main.js last line do this `export default App;`  [code](https://snack.expo.io/@vinil.prabhu/fd9160)